# How to use float filter to show just two digits after decimal point?

Tags: flask, jinja2, number-formatting

I am using Flask/Jinja2 template to show a number using `|float` filter.

Here is my code

```
{% set proc_err = nb_err|length / sum * 100 %}
({{proc_err|float}}%)
```

Output is a bit awkward:

```
17/189 (8.99470899471%)
```

I am looking for a way to make the places after dot limited to a number e.g. 2.

Desired output:

```
17/189 (8.99%)
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It turns to be quite simple:

My code:

```
{% set proc_err = nb_err|length / sum * 100 %}
({{proc_err|float}}%)
```

Can be changed a bit with:

```
{% set proc_err = nb_err|length / sum * 100 %}
({{'%0.2f' % proc_err|float}}%)
```

or using ***format***:

```
({{'%0.2f'| format(proc_err|float)}}%)
```

Reference can be found here on [jinja2 github issue 70](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues/70)

Comment: Is there a way to set a certain precision (like 0.3f) as a default in the current template? Just to avoid repetition ?

Answer (score 88):

You can use `round` to format a `float` to a given precision.

Extracted from [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#round):

`round(value, precision=0, method='common')`

Round the number to a given precision. The first parameter specifies the precision (default is `0`), the second the rounding method:

- `common` rounds either up or down
- `ceil` always rounds up
- `floor` always rounds down

If you don’t specify a method `common` is used.

```
{{ 42.55|round }}
    -> 43.0
{{ 42.55|round(1, 'floor') }}
    -> 42.5
```

Note that even if rounded to `0` precision, a `float` is returned. If you need a real integer, pipe it through `int`:

```
{{ 42.55|round|int }}
    -> 43
```

Comment: Except that `round(2)` will not return '42.00' ever, even if you have to serialize a `Decimal()` value.

Comment: @lol the question is about rounding not formatting. Even if the OP wanted the formatting. Printing decimals deals also with locales. Rounding is a mathematical operation while printing a formatted value is only visual.  In OP question though is better to print 100% than 100.00% ;)

Comment: Yes you are correct, and have caught me dropping an embarrassing sneaky hack into the codebase. Lol!

Answer (score 37):

Here is one approach ::

```
{{ "%.2f"|format(result) }}
```

Tweak it as you like :)

Answer (score -4):

(I'm assuming you use to Ionic v2)

Use this front-end code:

```
<div *ngIf="device.usage > 0">
   {{ Round(device.usage)}} min  
</div>
```

and put the following function into the .ts file:

```
Round(number):number
{
    return parseFloat(Number((number/1000) / 60).toFixed(2)); 
}
```