# How to set the default float format for Jinja in Flask?

Tags: python, format, flask, jinja2

I am using Jinja in Flask, I want to make all float looks like `123.45` by default in all my html page, not to keep too many digits after decimal point. I don't want to format every float  one by one in the template file. How can I do it ?

Comment: try it convert to `str()`

Comment: EDIT: Ah, you specifically don't want to format each one. Sorry, ignore this comment. Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260155/how-to-use-float-filter-to-show-just-two-digits-after-decimal-point

Comment: Looking through the Jinja code, I'm not sure it's possible - you could use the [round](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#round) filter, but that's another change for each float. I can only suggest writing a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-filters), which does something like `return "%.2f" % (value,)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can using [context processor](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#context-processors) for create custome filter for this.

i have copy from flask official documentation for doing this problem.

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def format_price(amount):
        return u'{0:.2f}{1}'.format(amount)
    return dict(format_price=format_price)
```

You can pass all value using this filter with

```
{{ format_price(0.33) }}
```

hopefully answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could also look into using the decimal module:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

here's a quick example taken from the above docs:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> rounded_num = Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
>>> rounded_num
Decimal('0.14')
```

by using this module all of the floats in your application will be nicely cast to two digits after the decimal.