# is there an equivalent to the javascript toPrecision() function in jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

In javascript numerical values can be displayed with two significant digits using the toPrecision(2) function. Is there an equivalent in jinja2?

Answer (score 0):

not sure why my question got down voted... I think its a perfectly good question... I found the answer myself, if anybody is interested

```
({{'%0.2f'| format(value|float)}}%)
```

however, this question might be a duplicate of [How to use float filter to show just two digits after decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260155/how-to-use-float-filter-to-show-just-two-digits-after-decimal-point)