# Round Decimal number in jinja 2

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to round a decimal number this is my number and my code

```
68.125 
the output should be 68.13 and I get 68.12
```

code:

```
{% set v_cuotas = doc.saldo_contrato/doc.plazo %}
VALUE: <span class="texto_liviano"></span>{{v_cuotas|round(2)|float}}<br>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260155/how-to-use-float-filter-to-show-just-two-digits-after-decimal-point

Comment: Yes I am, removing float the value is the same 68.12 and I want 68.13

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example, that produces the desired rounding looks like this:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> Decimal(Decimal('68.125').quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))                               
Decimal('68.13')
```

You can also write a [custom Jinja filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#custom-filters) if you want use it the same way like the built in `round` filter.